# Is there an alternative way to start Debugging Session much quicker?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

Is there an alternative way to start Debugging Session in visual Studio a bit more quicker when it comes asp.Net development?

I am used to press F5. How can I decrease the build time before starting the Debugger?

thanks

Comment: A faster machine will definitely help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, when debugging ASP.Net code, most of the start up delay is from launching the development server.  I think it stays running after the first debug session, so subsequent runs are quick.

Unfortunately, there's not really another way to debug web pages.  There's got to be a server somewhere to process the code.  You can attach to a running web server and debug that way, but using the attach dialog is more of a PITA than the startup delay, IMO.

There is the option of starting Cassini from the commandline on boot, apparently.  Never tried it, though.  See [here](http://thoughtjelly.blogspot.com/2009/05/launch-cassini-from-command-line.html).

Comment: I've had a good bit of success using the shortcut keys to attach to the current w3p.exe process. Alt-'D' -> 'P' -> tap 'W' key until w3p.exe is selected. I'd recommend this approach if the debug takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

I always start my web applications without a debugger. When I want to debug I attach the debugger to the process (menu Tools - Attach to process...). This has the advantage that the application doesn't start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I used is to avoid code-behind based code. If you concentrate your C# or VB code in custom controls, and ensure all HTML is done in ASPX/ASCX (to keep a clean separation between UI and Business code), you can just press F5 on the browser (not Visual Studio) when you only change HTML content (once the web server IIS or VSWebDev is started of course), because, as you know, you don't need to compile a Visual Studio project to ensure ASP.NET markup files are recompiled: this is done on the fly by the ASP.NET engine.

Of course, you still have to compile some .NET code C# or VB sometimes when you change business code, and redeploy it to the web server, but when there is a lot of markup changes to work on, this can save me a **lot of time**.